# Criar uma div com curva

Tags: css

Bom dia, gostaria de saber se é possivel e como fazer para criar uma `div` com essa curva em U para cima e para baixo usando apenas `css`, tentei de várias maneiras e não consegui.

Obrigado.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 4):

Recomendo sempre que fizer uma pergunta aqui, por algum código, ou exemplo visual com código no http://jsfiddle.net/ por exemplo. É interessante mostrar algum esforço.

Minha solução é essa [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nqyobut2/):

Html:

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="curve curve-top">
</div>
<div class="curve curve-bottom">
</div>
</div>
```

Css:

```
  div.wrapper {
      background-color:black;
       width:500px;
  }

  div.curve {
    background-color:white;
    width:500px;
    height:150px;
  }

  div.curve-top{   
      border-bottom-left-radius:70%;
      border-bottom-right-radius:70%;
  }

  div.curve-bottom {  
      margin-top: 50px;
      border-top-left-radius:70%;
      border-top-right-radius:70%;
  }
```